# Maple: How do I type "solve" with an arrow under?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, maple, symbolic-computation

I am trying to learn using Maple 18 (Mac).
I have defined a function with a list of X and Y values.

> f := x->LinReg(X, Y, x)

Now I would like to output the unknown "x" value that correlates with a known "y" value (e.g. 30).
According to the instruction manual, that I have, the way to do it is using this command:

[image: Output x command]

I just can't figure out how to type "solve" with an arrow under it.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED:
Screenshot of the commandwindow
[image: Screenshot of the commandwindow]

Comment: Right click the expression once you have entered it and then click on solve in the menu that opens. That would give you the arrow with the solve

Comment: You can also explicitly type the command `solve(f(x)=30,x);`.

Comment: In fact the solution by @Eff is better and is what's used most in practice as far as what I've seen

Comment: Thanks to both of You. I have tried both solutions. @JEET TRIVEDI's solution gives me a lot of choices for "solve". Tried them all, but without any luck. @Eff solution also without luck. Problem might be something else? I just get a warning saying Warning, solving for expressions other than names or functions is not recommended.
`Error, (in solve) a constant is invalid as a variable, -3, -1, 1, 2, 4`.

Comment: Could you provide more context on what you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: I believe it's the way you have defined f(x), instead of $f:=x\rightarrow \text{LinReg(X,Y,x)}$, try defining it as $f(x):=\text{LinReg(X,Y,x)}$

Comment: Now it ask me to verify the expression, because it is ambigious (see [link](http://imgur.com/tF4uqNg)). I chose "function definition", but no change. The error remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19660/discussion-between-jeet-trivedi-and-chmodder).

Comment: I don't have Maple at hand to test this right now, but I believe the error you're getting is caused by the fact that you have assigned a value to $x$ sometime earlier. (Specifically, it looks like $x := -3, -1, 1, 2, 4$.) Try unsetting $x$, restarting the engine or just using some other variable name in ${\rm solve}()$ instead.

Comment: You are right about restarting the engine. I think either the Gym package or Maple might have been acting up, because after a lot of help from @JEET TRIVEDI, we where able to rule out the inputted commands. I restarted Maple and then It "magically" worked. Problem solved, but thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

**LinReg** seems to be a command in some special package **Gym**, which is not part of standard Maple.

But here is what I might do using standard Maple.

```
> with(Statistics):
X:= [-3,-1, 1, 2,4];
Y:= [-1,0.5,5, 6,8];
F:= LinearFit(a*x+b, X, Y, x);
```

$$ F := 1.38356164383562\; x+2.86986301369863$$

```
> solve(F = 30, x);
```

$$19.60891089$$

Comment: You are right about the Gym package. I think either that or Maple might have been acting up, because after a lot of help from @JEET TRIVEDI, we where able to rule out the inputted commands. I restarted Maple and then It "magically" worked. Problem solved, but thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I think either the installed expansion package "Gym" or Maple might have been acting up, because after a lot of help from @JEET TRIVEDI, we where able to rule out the inputted commands. I restarted Maple and then It "magically" worked. Problem solved.
Thanks to everybody who helped me solve the problem.

[image: Working]